# How to make other controls see a collection of DataTables in a custom control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, custom-controls

I am building a custom compoment that can be dragged from the toolbox onto a form.
It exposes a List of type DataTable, and this works well so far.

What I am missing is that when I put a BindingSource on the same form, in the designer the BindingSource does not see my collection of DataTables. So I cannot select one of the DataTables from the custom component. I know I can do this in code but that is not the idea, I want to do it in the designer.

How can I accomplish this ?

The code for the public collection of DataTables is this

```
[Serializable]
public partial class gttDataModule : Component
{
    private List<DataTable> _dataTables = new List<DataTable>();


    public List<DataTable> DataTables
    {
        get { return _dataTables; }
        set { _dataTables = value; }
    }
```

The collection of DataTables is populated and filled with columns and everything, see also the attached image.
Everything works except that BindingSources and other controls that can accept a DataTable as DataSource do not see this collection.
Is there a way to accomplish this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please click `DataSource`-> `Other Data Sources`->`List Instances`-> choose the datatable you added in the custom control to set the `datasource` for `bindingSouce` control.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunate my DataTables doe not show up in `Other Data Sources` . My question is how to accomplish it so they will show up there

Comment: @GuidoG, I used vs2019, It seems that you are using vs2015. Can you use vs2019 to test it?

Comment: No I am sorry, I only have VS 2015 available here. So you are saying that it would work in VS 2019 ? If I was sure about that I can push my employer to finally upgrade

Comment: @GuidoG, currently it works well in vs2019 based on my test. If you can not use vs2019 in your computer, you can test it in virtual machine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `you can test it in virtual machine` Can I get a VS 2019 in a virtual machine somewhere or what do you mean ?

Comment: @GuidoG, I just want you to test it in other computer environment if you worry about the solution. Please ignore the virtual machine, it is my fault.